# how to encode string with spaces into html valid id?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, encode

I have `class`items whose unique identifier is their `string`field. I am set these elements in html using Razor(C#). I handle it for javascript. I need to convert strings from `example`"Mr. Smith" to `id`"{2342-2341-2324-...}" or at `Base64`"92384098230...". And then use javascript to get the value from the encoded string. How to do it in C# and Javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript)

Comment: No! I was trying to do this before I asked the question. In Razor: System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(; In Js: atob(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following-

```
C# - Uri.EscapeDataString(String)
```

And to convert the above value in JavaScript-

```
js - unescape(string) or decodeURI(string)
```

If you would like to do the reverse you can use

```
C# - Uri.UnEscapeDataString(string) & js - escape(string) or encodeURI (string)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what need. But it doesn't work - when converting back, I get ÐÐ²Ð¾Ð´%20Ð¸Ð½ÑÐ¾ÑÐ¼Ð°ÑÐ¸Ð¸

Comment: Can you share a bit more details? C# what's is the original text and escaped text and in js unescaped text?

Comment: I did it! The "unescape" method is deprecated, I replaced it with "decodeURI": C#:`Uri.EscapeDataString(item.Name)` => Javascript:`decodeURI(itemId)`. Its work! Thanks!

Comment: Added decodeURI in the answer - however https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

Comment: Please mark it as answered as it has helped .